# Reset scoped container in inversifyjs

Tags: typescript, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, reference-counting, inversifyjs

I'm implementing a scoped container architecture such that a new `container` is created for every Express request (or apollographql request). I have a lifecycle method that can be called after we're done sending the response, which is good for cleaning up and freeing memory, and this method can reference the context of the request we're done serving. In that `context` I have a reference to the `inversifyjs container` that I created earlier so I can reference that `container` in the cleanup method, how can I `delete that container`?

```
function ScopedContainer(userId: number) {
  const container = new Container();
  container.bind<number>(TYPES.userId).toConstantValue(userId);
  //rest of bindings container.bind ...
  return container;
}

async({req, res}) => {
  const { headers } = req;
  const { userId } = headers;
  const container = ScopedContainer(clientId);
  const context = { container }
  ///...
}

willSendResponse(({container}) => {
  // how to instruct inversifyjs to ditch all references to container?
  // something like container.destroy?
});
```

I want to make sure that this `container` will not stay there after the http request is done, causing huge memory leak. Problem is I'm not sure it will be garbage collected as reference count reaches zeros. I'm also using `lazyInject` from `inversify-inject-decorators`

Is there any `inversifyjs` `container` API like destroy or reset method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no persistent reference to container instance inside inversify lib. It is temporarily ref'ed by `Context` in `_planAndResolve` private method, but is released upon return so no worry.

Conceptually, a container instance should be the top level resolver. All other services in the system are sorta "owned" by container, but nobody should own container except userland code.

En bref, as long as you stick to the rule: **only use `container` in your composition root**, like in `inversify.config.ts`, you're safe.

In your example it's less obvious how many other entities get hold to the `container` reference. If it's only the `context` object that you pass along express middlewares, then as soon as the request handling is done, `context` is deref'ed and so is `container` waiting to be GC. No further "cleanup" necessary.

Comment: Is there a way for a non-express (frontend instead of backend) project to keep a single container reference, and reset it in a way that it will recreate a new instance of the services I need to inject/get?

Comment: Sure. Container only helps with the IoC pattern, as of how would you like to consume it, it's totally up to you.  Just think of it as a master entity that spawns worker/service instances. And you're free to put yet another supervising entity on top of that master (container).

Comment: What about resetting that instance without making a new container? Is there an API/trick to do that?

Comment: @Zorgatone How about post another question with some code to show the problem? I can take a look.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66820199 @hackape