# Clear inversify-js container and resolve new service instances

Tags: typescript, react-native, singleton, inversion-of-control, inversifyjs

I have a [react-native](https://reactnative.dev/) application frontend using [inversify-js](https://inversify.io/).

I've structured some service classes to use [IOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) (using an inversify container), such services intended to be shared as just one singleton instances among other services. They have an init/destroy method to help to clear up the services' internal state.

The init/destroy mechanism works fine but on top of that, it would be nice to have a way to "clear" the inversify container singletons, to rebuild all my singleton services from scratch.

Example:

src/services/A.ts

```
@injectable()
export class A extends Service {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  init() {
    super.init();

    // [...] Initialize A's state
  }

  destroy() {
    // [...] Destroy A's state

    super.destroy();
  }

  method() {
    // [...] Provide functionality to other services (maintaining A's state)
  }
}
```

src/services/B.ts

```
@injectable()
export class B extends Service {
  constructor(
    b: B // receive injected instance of service A using constructor injection (inversify)
  ) {
    super();
  }

  init() {
    super.init();

    // [...] Initialize B's state
  }

  destroy() {
    // [...] Destroy B's state

    super.destroy();
  }

  method() {
    // [...] Provide functionality to other services (maintaining B's state, using also service A)
    this.a.method();
  }
}
```

src/inversify/container.ts

```
export const containerModule = new ContainerModule((bind) => {
  // Services
  bind<A>(A).toSelf().inSingletonScope();
  bind<B>(B).toSelf().inSingletonScope();
});

const container = new Container();

container.load(containerModule);

export default container;
```

index.ts

```
let a = container.get<A>(A);
let b = container.get<A>(B);

// [...] use services

// Destroy services (es: logout/reload app)
a.destroy();
b.destroy();

// Here I'd also like to "reset" the container
// container.reset(); // like this?

// [...] After some time (maybe login again?)

// I'd like these two to be new singleton instances (!== from previous a,b)
a = container.get<A>(A);
b = container.get<A>(B);
```

I should be able to maybe "unload" the ContainerModule from the Container (`container.unload(containerModule)`) and "load" it again? Seems hacky though, I was looking for comparable solutions.

I looked into this question but, in the end, didn't need the same "reset" functionality anyway: [Reset scoped container in inversifyjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65472688/reset-scoped-container-in-inversifyjs/66815364)

Comment: Hey there, I see this. But it’s really late in my timezone so allow me to get back to you like 12 hours later.

Comment: Thanks, take your time there's no rush

Comment: hello @Zorgatone, I'm trying to use inversify for my react-native app, but I'm getting following errors:
Require cycle: node_modules/inversify/lib/syntax/binding_on_syntax.js -> node_modules/inversify/lib/syntax/binding_when_syntax.js -> node_modules/inversify/lib/syntax/binding_on_syntax.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
 ERROR  TypeError: Reflect.hasOwnMetadata is not a function. (In 'Reflect.hasOwnMetadata(metadataKey, annotationTarget)', 'Reflect.hasOwnMetadata' is undefined).
Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I suggest in the other answer is to simply ditch the current `container` and create a fresh instance, very clean and easy to understand.

But then I look into the source code and find that such feature is already included.

`container.unbindAll()` it is!

This API unconditionally resets the container to a fresh state (almost fresh, explain later) without the need to create a new instance. [Link to source code](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/54a46b2fe338507e87ebae4fe9b14f665a90237f/src/container/container.ts#L174).

I said "almost fresh" earlier, this is because container also has a less known (at least to me) feature called [snapshots](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/container_snapshots.md#container-snapshots). Turns out you can even have multiple snapshots of binding setups stored in one container.

Interesting . So if you make a snapshot of a empty container before registering any binding, and restore it later, it’s effective a "reset".

Lastly, `container.unload(containerModule)` is totally valid, not hacky at all. May call this one selective reset

If you read the source code you’ll see, under the hood of all these methods, it’s all about modifying the internal `_bindingDictionary`. That’s where all the bindings are stored.

Comment: I'll make some tests and let you know if it'll work, and the solution I'll go with

Comment: Just realized what you really mean by “reset”. Guess for your case the snapshot feature is best match. After load the module, you take a snapshot. When reset, just restore the snapshot.

Comment: Yeah, I was just thinking that's the safest solution

Comment: But unload then load the module should also work. Test and see.

Answer (score 4):

Use `@preDestroy` decorator for a class method. [Inversify-docs#preDestroy](https://www.jsdocs.io/package/inversify#preDestroy)

> This decorator will run before a service is unbinded for any cached instance. For this reason, only bindings in singleton scope can contain a method with this decorator.

```
@preDestroy
destroy() {
  console.log('Service is about to be unbounded. Destroy');
}
```